# Is there a built in function to select a candle based on time?

Tags: pine-script

For example, I want to change the barcolor of the 12:00 pm candle.

```
Something like this:

barcolor(time_of_candle == 12:00pm? color.blue: na)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hour and minute in exchange timezone.

```
barcolor(hour == 12 and minute == 00 ? color.blue: na)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That worked perfectly! One more for ya. Is there an easy way to get the first and last day of each month? I found dayofmonth == 1 but sometimes stocks begin on the 2nd  of the month and end on 28-31st.

Comment: Try the following condition to determine the first day of the month `change(dayofmonth) < 0`.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you bro.